# Wi-Fi Scanner Not Allowed in AppStore

Tags: ios

I have found many blog posts and websites mentioning that apple doesn't allow wi-fi scanners anymore, or that such apps will be rejected later.

But why are there so many apps in the store that can scan wifi (such as Fing)?. Why haven't they been rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to release app for Wifi scanning. But you need to get NEHotspot Helper entitlements from Apple and add to your project. This entitlement will provide the scanned wifi list near to your device.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspothelper

You need to submit a request to Apple. They will review your request and provide entitlements.

Not sure how you implemented wifi scanning without apple's entitlement. Using any private API's?

Then it got high chances for rejection.